# What exactly is the difference between notify function and notice resource in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I can display a custom message in two ways in Puppet, either by

```
notice("My extra information as a function")
```

or by

```
notify{"My extra information as a resource":}
```

Things in common:

- Both get evaluated on Puppet Master.
- Both have access to facts.
- If message is composed from variables, both would display the same string.

Things that are different:

- The order of execution. The functions gets evaluated first, during the compilation phase. Only then the resources are fulfilled.
- The `notify` can be set as a virtual or exported resource, with important implications, which are unavailable for `notice`
- The `notice` cannot display the calling path (there is no `withpath => true`)
- `notice` has a sister function `fail`, which has a power to fail the compilation of the manifest. `notify` cannot do that, since it starts working when the compilation is already done.

I have a feeling that I missed important aspects or maybe I was wrong in some parts. Would someone better with Puppet than me fill more details?

Comment: notice is also useful in functions which will be called many times and thus any notify resource would fail the uniqueness requirement for its name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`notify` sends a log message to the `puppet agent` whereas the `notice` function logs a message on the `puppet server/master` in the `notice` log-level. The same goes for the `err`, `debug`, `info`, and `warning` functions.

Keep in mind, `notify` is a managed resource, whereas `notice` is a function executed on the master.